# How would I find matches between records in two lists based on a combination of variables in R?

Tags: r

I have two data frames...

```
> dim(df.x)
[1] 2120   5
> dim(df.y)
[1] 125    3
```

I'd like to identify records in data frame x that match data frame y for both variable 1 and variable 2 (but not for any other variables).
 
I suppose the typical way to do this in a lot of languages would be to do nested for statements and to compare each record in x to each record in y and stop and index the hits. But I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this in R.

(I'd prefer to stick to base R or "out-of-the-box" R, if possible, rather than some of the higher-level packages.)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You can probably just `merge()` to get the overlap with base R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `merge()` from base-R which gives an inner join by default. The code would be something like:

```
common = merge(df.x,df.y,by=c("var1","var2"))
```

`var1` and `var2` are your variables.